# Data validation with Javascript in mvc

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I would like to validate some data in a form. I'm using an open source application called FusionInvoice (https://www.fusioninvoice.com) and customizing it. This app is mostly in php but has a combination of js, css, and html. Bellow is an example code:

```
 <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label"><?php echo lang('phone_number'); ?>: </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="client_phone" id="client_phone" value="<?php echo $this->mdl_clients->form_value('client_phone'); ?>">
                    </div>
```

So here it is! Would it possible to add a data validation inside a div tag using javascript. There are too much layering with this app so I don't want to break it missing with the controller and models. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But what kind of validation do you want to perform?

Comment: Just do not rely on Javascript validation. **Always** filter and validate any and all user-provided data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, jQuery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org) is an excellent client side validation library. However, Sverri Olsen is correct, you should **Always** validate user submitted data server side as well as client side. Client side validation is only for the user convenience, e.g. they don't have to wait for a client-server round trip to see that they typed in their phone number incorrectly.